# Throw System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException while word file read using openxml API

Tags: c#, exception, openxml, isolatedstorage

We are update document using openxml programatically. while we start to read file using below code, Exception throws at that time.

This exception only throws when file size is bigger.

`using (WordprocessingDocument wdoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(strPath, true))`

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(m_fileName, true))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

            foreach (CustomXmlPart customXmlPart in mainPart.CustomXmlParts)
            {

                bool exists = false;
                using (XmlTextReader xReader = new XmlTextReader(customXmlPart.GetStream(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
                {
                    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                    xReader.MoveToContent();
                    exists = xReader.NamespaceURI.Equals("urn:TTCProperties:namespace");
                    if (exists)
                    {

                        xmlDocument.Load(xReader);
                        XmlNodeList n = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Status");
                        if (n != null)
                        {
                            foreach (XmlNode curr in n)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(curr.InnerText);
                                curr.InnerText = "New String";
                            }
                        }
                        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(customXmlPart.GetStream());
                        Stream stream = customXmlPart.GetStream();
                        stream.SetLength(0);
                        using (StreamWriter ts = new StreamWriter(stream))
                            ts.Write(xmlDocument.InnerXml);

                        wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save(mainPart);
```

how can resolve this runtime Exception during file reading

Comment: `Everything works fine but when we protect the document also programactially using openxml for editing` I don't know what that sentence means.

Comment: Can you provide more code than just one line?

Comment: @mjwills Sorry.. Please refer this description .

Comment: @Itsme1 Please refer this whole code

Comment: _Where_ does it throw?

Comment: @AluanHaddad its throw while using (WordprocessingDocument wdoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(strPath, true)) line execute in code

Comment: Just an educated guess, but it appears that Isolated Storage must be accessed via a different set of stream [readers/writers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: What exception are you getting ? Post the exception trace in the question.

Comment: @SRIDHARAN Throws System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException:

Comment: please paste the complete stack trace here.